# Compare 7 words to eachother to see if 5 of them are equal. How?

Tags: c#, string, random, compare

I have seven words in the array:

```
string[7] = {x,x,x,x,x,x,x};
```

the x is generated from another array:

```
string[4]={a,b,c,d};
```

that means each x can be either a or b or c or d. It is randomly generated. this could be an example:

```
string[7]= {a,a,d,a,a,c,a}
```

my question is how can I check if there are five x which has the same value?

This is for a poker app Im working on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Linq to find the largest number of equal items and test if this is 5 or more:

```
int maxCount = s.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Count()).Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
    List<string> values = new List<string> {"a", "a", "d","a", "a", "c", "a"};

    int count = values.FindAll(id => id == "a").Count();
```

Comment: This would only find out the number of "a" values.  Remember that he's looking for 5 values that match - but the values can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the similar items and find it any group have five or more

```
from word in new [] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b" }
group word by word into wordGroup
where wordGroup.Count() >= 5
select wordGroup.Key
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array, after that you are sure that if there are five or more of the same value, the middle value is one of them. Count how many:

```
Array.Sort(words);
int cnt = 0;
Array.ForEach(words, s => { if (s == words[3]) cnt++; });
```